# 12.04 Installation Not Completing

Tags: installation

Here's the problem I've been having, installing from a CD I burned, in the 'Try Ubuntu' mode: I get to the point where I'm asked to fill in my name, the computer name, etc.; after I press 'Continue', the installation window closes and the installation doesn't go any further - i.e., the system doesn't seem to start actually installing, and I'm never asked to restart the computer or do anything else. All that happens is I get the desktop and a busy cursor...for seven and a half hours. Restarting the computer after waiting that seven and a half hours resulted in nothing but a '_' blinking on and off at the point where I'd expect Ubuntu to boot if it'd installed properly.

What am I doing wrong, or, failing my being at fault somehow, what can I do to fully install Ubuntu? I've tried bypassing 'Try Ubuntu' and just doing 'Install Ubuntu' from the get-go, but it always ends up having an 'unrecoverable error' (again, at the point after I fill in my name, computer name, etc.). Forgive my lack of knowledge; I'm a fairly basic user and I don't mind admitting that this problem has put me out of my depth. Thank you.

Comment: 7 and half hous ! Unimaginable
BTW CAN YOU PROVIDE MORE INFO ABOUT YOUR PC SPEC?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the triangle at the bottom of the install window--there is a hidden console log that tells you what the installer is doing. It could be stuck at some point and not moving forward, hence taking 7+ hours. I had this happen, and fixed it as described here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/173755/fixing-an-unfinished-installation-of-12-04

Answer (score 0):

Maybe cd bad sectors have caused that. Because at the time you are filling in the name feilds, the process of copying files is started(as far as my CD-rom is concerned). I have been using USB to install fresh copy of ubuntu and it goes on without any problem. Try installing it using Universal USB installer and use USB to install a fresh copy of Ubuntu. Well, if you are using Windows system, then its quite easy to install by Wubi installer with "install inside window" option.